# Why the results of Cox regression are different between coxph() and cph() in rms package

Tags: r, cox-model, rms

I found the predicted **hazard** (the h(t) of Cox regression) through **Predict()** and **cph()** in **rms** package was different from common **coxph()**.

```
URL   <- "https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/data/Rossi.txt"
Rossi <- read.table(URL, header=TRUE)
Rossi[1:3, c("week", "arrest", "fin", "age", "prio")]  # looks like this
#week arrest fin age prio
#1   20      1  no  27    3
#2   17      1  no  18    8
#3   25      1  no  19   13

library(survival)                                     
fitCPH <- coxph(Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin + age + prio, data=Rossi)

risk<-predict(fitCPH,type="risk")
print(head(risk),digits = 6)
#[1] 0.852426 2.531330 3.842432 0.649217 1.458157 0.946252

library(rms)
dd<-datadist(Rossi)
options(datadist = 'dd')

fitCPH2 <- cph(Surv(week, arrest) ~ fin + age + prio, data=Rossi)

#Take the 1st individual in **Rossi** as a sample:fin="no",age=27,prio=3
rms::Predict(fitCPH2,fin="no",age=27,prio=3,fun=exp,type = "predictions",ref.zero =FALSE,conf.int=0.95,digits = 4)  
#  fin age prio     yhat     lower    upper
#1  no  27    3 1.013916 0.8171016 1.258137

#Response variable (y):  

#Limits are 0.95 confidence limits
```

I thought **yhat** should be 0.852426 (the first number of **risk**), but why it was 1.013916?

Comment: I think that this might be a software-specific issue related to the reference situation used in the two software packages. In the `survival` package "the reference value ... is the mean covariate within strata."  In `rms` I recall that the reference value is chosen differently, based on the `datadist` for the data. Check the corresponding help pages for the packages and make sure that you have specified the same reference values. If you still find a discrepancy, repost with the new results.

Comment: @EdM Sorry, I really don't understand the function datalist well enough to know how to set its parameters. I know the default  for coxph() is `reference="sample"`，which means **use the overall means** (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.coxph.html) . But how couldI change the parameter of datalist to make the `reference` of these two functions consistent?

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to reconcile the two Cox-model fitting functions that way. It will only make your head hurt. (At least it makes mine hurt.)

**A Cox model only defines linear predictors and associated hazards relative to a reference scenario.** After the model is fit, you can then generate a baseline hazard over time for that reference scenario. That baseline hazard is then used to generate survival predictions based on **differences of covariate values from the reference scenario**.

I think about that baseline hazard as functionally equivalent to the intercept in a linear regression model. If you change the reference values used for a predictor, then the intercept in a linear regression model will change and the baseline hazard function in a Cox model will change.

The `survival` package uses the overall means *of the covariate values* as the reference scenario. The `rms` package stores the linear-predictor values as *differences from the mean linear predictor* value. For your case, that gives:

```
exp(fitCPH2$linear.predictor[[1]])
# [1] 1.013916
```

which is the value that you found. If you specify `ref.zero=TRUE` then the result is relative to the "Adjust to" values in the `datadist`:

```
dd$limits["Adjust to",c("fin","age","prio")]
#                  fin age prio
# Adjust to         no  23    2

Predict(fitCPH2,fin="no",age=27,prio=3,fun=exp,type = "predictions",ref.zero =TRUE,conf.int=0.95,digits = 4)
#   fin age prio      yhat     lower    upper
# 1  no  27    3 0.8424147 0.7071496 1.003554
```

which is closer to what you found with `coxph` but still not the same, as the "Adjust to" values in `rms` aren't the same as the mean values used by `survival`.

```
fitCPH$means
#    finyes       age      prio 
#  0.000000 24.597222  2.983796
```

Within each package, everything will work OK in terms of predictions. But it takes some work to try to get them to use the same reference values. The end of the help page for `datadist` shows how to do it if you really need to. You need to change the "Adjust to" values, redefine the `datadist` option to the new version, `update()` the original fit, and specify `ref.zero=TRUE` in the call to `Predict()`:

```
dd$limits["Adjust to","age"] <- fitCPH$means[["age"]]
dd$limits["Adjust to","prio"] <- fitCPH$means[["prio"]]
options(datadist="dd")
fitCPH2adj <- update(fitCPH2)
Predict(fitCPH2adj,fin="no",age=27,prio=3,fun=exp,type = "predictions",ref.zero =TRUE,conf.int=0.95,digits = 4)
#   fin age prio    yhat     lower     upper
# 1  no  27    3 0.85244 0.7726731 0.9404416
```

But then those confidence intervals are for the *difference from the new reference values*, which might not be what you want. In particular, the width of the confidence interval is 0 at the new reference values:

```
Predict(fitCPH2adj,fin="no",age= fitCPH$means[["age"]],prio= fitCPH$means[["prio"]],fun=exp,type = "predictions",ref.zero =TRUE,conf.int=0.95,digits = 4)
#   fin      age     prio yhat lower upper
# 1  no 24.59722 2.983796    1     1     1
```

I can't think of anything that you can do with a `coxph` model that you can't with a `cph` model, provided that you follow the necessary syntax changes (like using `strat()` instead of `strata()` for defining strata). It's much simpler and less error-prone to work within a single package for such things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what really confuses me is that I don't think that the output from `type="risk"` in `coxph()` is a **relative** hazard？Shouldn't the relative risk (hazard) be `exp(fitCPH$coefficient)`?   The `0.852426 `  was just the **h(t)** of hazard function: h(t)=h0(t)*exp (β1X1+β2X2+β3X3+……+βnXn) .

Comment: May I ask if it is possible to specify the ``dd$limits`` by myself ?

Comment: @tumidou the "risk" output type from a Cox model **always** is relative to the reference scenario that the software chose. In your terminology, the value of `h0(t)` is the value for the baseline hazard **at the chosen reference scenario**.  As `coxph` and `cph` make different default choices for the baseline scenario, the default reported "risk" values differ. I've edited the answer to show how to redefine `dd$limits` if you really need to.